# Unable to navigate using router.nagivate in angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I am using `"angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15"` (with `"typescript": "^1.8.10",`) and `AppComponent` is my main component which is just working as shell and handles navigation:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/router';
import {LoginComponent} from "./login/login.component";
import {RegisterComponent} from "./registration/register.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})

@RouteConfig([
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'Login',
        component: LoginComponent,
        useAsDefault: true
    },
    {
        path: '/register',
        name: 'Register',
        component: RegisterComponent
    }
])
export class AppComponent {

}
```

Both `LoginComponent` and `RegisterComponent` has links to navigate to each other.

This is how I am trying to navigate:

```
@Component({
   ...
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit{

    constructor(private _router: Router) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
       // some stuffs
    }

    goToRegister(){
        this._router.navigate(['Register']); //also tried this._router.navigate(['/Register']);
    }
}
```

And similarly:

```
@Component({
   ...
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit{

    constructor(private _router: Router) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // some stuffs
    }

    goToLogin(){
        this._router.navigate(['Login']); // also tried this._router.navigate(['/Login']);
    }
}
```

But when I am trying to navigate, the url changes for a moment and then app **reloads** itself to the same page/component. There is no error shown in the Console.

Comment: Just Tip - Remove `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` and put at the time of bootstraping your app.

Comment: If it is only added on the root component it's OK, but don't add it to other components. If you add it to `bootstrap()` don't add it to any component.

Comment: I have added it in the `AppComponent` only. And just tried moving it to `bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);` still same behavior.

Comment: Can you try to make it reproduce in a Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/xZXCUL?p=info ?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I am trying to reproduce in Plunker, but unable to. Can you still check the project.

Comment: Unable how? Does it work as expected in the Plunker? I don't know what to look for. Your code looks fine beside what I explained in my answer. I need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also found this same behavior you are seeing here in a project I am working on as well. In my case I saw this behavior in Chrome and Safari, but Firefox seemed to be unaffected.

<s>I unsure of the root cause, but the way I was triggering the `router.navigate` was</s>

`<button class="btn btn-default" (click)="lookupName()">Lookup</button>`

Changing this to

`<a class="btn btn-default" (click)="lookupName()">Lookup</a>`

fixed the issue for me. May not be the answer you are looking for, but this was driving me crazy, and am happy this fixed it for me.

Looking into this a bit more changing the element to an `<a></a>` is less than ideal as it removes the nice form submit on enter functionality. I managed to fix it while keeping the same functionality as before and hope it helps you.

I changed my template from:

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="name" placeholder="Name" required>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" (click)="lookup()">Lookup</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

to look like this:

```
<form class="form-inline" (ngSubmit)="lookup()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="name" placeholder="Name" required>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Lookup</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This seems to fix the issue for me. I got the idea after looking at this: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

Use instead

```
this._router.navigate(['/Register'])
this._router.navigate(['/Login'])
```

if you route from a child component.

Comment: Tried it. Same behavior.